# How execute function on fixed time on mac os x?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I write a simple application for mac osx that works with system time to calculate some data, i want to run an specific routine every time clock come to 12:00
Is there any system api for this?
How i do this?

actually i have a status bar item in my app that show current day in month in any selected calendar like gregorian and islamic, and i want to this value will be sync with system time

Comment: And what will happen if your app isn't running at 12:00?

Comment: if so my app display wrong data in mac status bar

Comment: What if 12:00 doesn't exist on that day, or exists twice? (In Brazil, this happens due to daylight savings time)

Comment: actually i have a status bar item in my app that show current day in month in any selected calendar like gregorian and islamic, and i want to this value will be sync with system time

Answer (score -1):

If your routine is the method `- routine:(NSTimer *)timer` of `object`:

```
NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]; // Current time
NSTimeInterval then = ((int)now + 86400) % 86400; // Next 12am
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:then];
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:date interval:86400 target:object @selector(routine:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```